# What is the explanation behind the below declaration/keyword?

Tags: external, linkage

I would like to know what the following declarations do. I have seen them in a C code on MSVisual Studio Compiled code.

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)

I know somewhat that they are used to declare external linkage for functions(functional defined in different source file.But would like to know in detail how this works.

-Ajit

Answer (score 3):

The `extern "C"` part tells a C++ compiler that the item being declared should use C linkage, which means that the name will not be mangled (or will be mangled in the same way that a C compiler would).  This makes it so the item can be linked to from C code and most other languages as well, since C linkage is typically the standard used for that on a platform.

The `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` items are non-standard attributes that tell the compiler that the item should be exported (or imported) from a DLL. The `__declspec()` attribute is supported on MS compilers and probably other compilers that target Windows.  I'm not sure if GCC does or not. Other storage class attributes that can be specified with `__declspec()` (at least in MSVC) include `uuid()`, `naked`, `deprecated` and others that provide the compiler with information on how an object or function should be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

dllexport tells the compiler to generate a [.lib file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_link_library#Import_libraries).  dllimport tells the compiler to look in a .lib file for the function declaration (its definition will be in a dll).

Answer (score 1):

It means the functions/classes that follow it are visible and accessible across a DLL boundary so you can link against them and call them from other code